# Google AdSense does not resize when window size gets changed

Tags: javascript, css, adsense

Here is a related post from 2014: [Responsive Adsense ad resizing with screen orientation change (while using Bootstrap for layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952416/responsive-adsense-ad-resizing-with-screen-orientation-change-while-using-boots)

It looks like the resizing feature was beta then but it's 2015.

The challenge is the same:

- Open a window with responsive AdSense -> AdSense adopts itself to the size
- Resize the window -> AdSense does not request a new version.

Now the docs on responsive resizing have been updated by google (source: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en)

They state:

> **Support for ad size changes after a screen orientation change**. If your responsive page changes its layout following a device orientation change (e.g., when a tablet or phone goes from portrait to landscape), we’ll request and load a new ad of the correct dimensions to fit the new page layout.

Well, either I do not understand it, or it does not work. Shouldn't this be working when I change the size of my window? Bootstraps responsive grid does so.

I am aware of various workarounds like media queries, reloading the js, having multiple ads for multiple sizes, but then the statement above does not make sense.

Do they really only include going fro portrait to landscape? How is this issued in the browser?

Edit: I do not have an advanced responsive ad, just a plain one, no customization of size or shape.
Edit2: The container in which the ad is, does change it's size based on bootstrap's media queries, so AdSense should always be able to determine the dimension of the ad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad ?

Comment: Well, I am using Firefox Developer Edition with the responsive design view, changing the size so width > height does not create a new request of the adsense API